# how to create new group in xmpp server

Tags: javascript, jquery, xmpp, openfire, strophe

Am using Strophe.js library for communication between my application with XMPP(Openfire) server.

I want add user with group,
How can i create new group?
How can i mention group name with add buddy query?

This is my code for adding new user

```
var str1=$pres({'xmlns':'jabber:client','from':xxx@example.com,'to':yyy@example.com,'type':'subscribe'}).c('nick',{'xmlns':'http://jabber.org/protocol/nick'}).t(userName);
 connection.send(str1.tree());
```

I refer XMPP extension over day but i cant find proper result

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to send a roster update.  [Read RFC 6121, Section 2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6121#section-2) for details.  You'll be sending this protocol:

```
<iq from='juliet@example.com/balcony'
    id='rs1'
    type='set'>
   <query xmlns='jabber:iq:roster'>
     <item jid='yyy@example.com' name='nick'>
        <group>My Group</group>
     </item>         
   </query>
</iq>
```

With code something like:

```
$iq({'type':'set'}).c('query',{'xmlns':Strophe.NS.ROSTER}) 
   .c('item', {'jid':'yyy@example.com','name':'nick'})
       .c('group').t('My Group')
```

Comment: Hai Joe in this case i cant add the user to particular group.,First i want create new group then only its possible.,Which extension will provide this

Comment: There's no such thing as an empty group in base XMPP.  You could store a list of empty groups separately, perhaps using PEP (XEP-0163: http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0163.html), or, failing that Private Storage (XEP-0049: http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0049.html).  For either of those, use a new namespace that you control, but don't expect other clients to be able to see the empty groups.  If you feel strongly about this, write a new XEP, and submit it to the XSF: http://xmpp.org/xmpp-protocols/xmpp-extensions/submitting-a-xep/

Answer (score 0):

I have made this Using below code.

XMPPRoomCoreDataStorage *rosterstorage =[[XMPPRoomCoreDataStorage alloc] init];
    XMPPRoom *xmppRoom = [[XMPPRoom alloc] initWithRoomStorage:rosterstorage jid:[XMPPJID jidWithString:@"MyFirstGroup@conference.test-desktop"] dispatchQueue:dispatch_get_main_queue()];

```
[xmppRoom activate:[[self appDelegate]xmppStream]];
[xmppRoom joinRoomUsingNickname:@"DeveloperQ" history:nil];

 [[[self appDelegate] xmppStream]  addDelegate:self delegateQueue:dispatch_get_main_queue()];
 [xmppRoom addDelegate:self  delegateQueue:dispatch_get_main_queue()];
```

Then

- (void)xmppRoomDidJoin:(XMPPRoom *)sender

{

NSXMLElement *iq = [NSXMLElement elementWithName:@"iq"];

```
[iq addAttributeWithName:@"id" stringValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"inroom-cr%@",groupName]]; 
[iq addAttributeWithName:@"to" stringValue::@"MyFirstGroup@conference.test-desktop"];
[iq addAttributeWithName:@"type" stringValue:@"set"];
NSXMLElement *query = [NSXMLElement elementWithName:@"query" xmlns:XMPPMUCOwnerNamespaceName];
NSXMLElement *xelem = [NSXMLElement elementWithName:@"x" xmlns:@"jabber:x:data"];
[xelem addAttributeWithName:@"type" stringValue:@"submit"];
[query addChild:xelem];
[iq addChild:query];
[[[self appDelegate] xmppStream] sendElement:iq];
```

}